# selecting sum of a row in child table with perticular id and compairing it to parent table

Tags: mysql, sql

hello I have a SQL DB with two tables.

common_fee_collection //parent table

common_fee_collection_headwise //child table

now the structure of this two tables are like this

`` CREATE TABLE `common_fee_collection` ( `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `admno` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, `amount` double(13,2) NOT NULL ); ``

this table contains rows which's `amount` column represent the sum of total amount in a lifetime

id = it's an auto increment ID with unique data

admno = a unique admission number

amount = the total amount combined from table  common_fee_collection_headwise.amount from all the rows in common_fee_collection_headwise.amount

`` CREATE TABLE `common_fee_collection_headwise` ( `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `moduleId` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, `receiptId` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, `amount` double(13,2) NOT NULL ) ``

id  AUTO_INCREMENT integer data

receiptId =this is the foreign key from common_fee_collection.id

amount= amount in a perticular transaction at a perticular time

now the question is I want to get the rows where common_fee_collection.amount is not equals SUM(common_fee_collection_headwise.amount). means the rows which are mismatched amount.

I have tried these three query but it gives wrong output or errors

1> `SELECT * FROM common_fee_collection WHERE amount <> SUM(common_fee_collection_headwise.amount) AND id=common_fee_collection_headwise.receiptId;`

this code gives error `#1111 - Invalid use of group function`

2> `SELECT * FROM common_fee_collection as com WHERE amount<>SUM(common_fee_collection_headwise.amount) AND id=common_fee_collection_headwise.receiptId`

this code gives error `#1111 - Invalid use of group function`

3> `SELECT * FROM common_fee_collection AS a JOIN common_fee_collection_headwise as b ON a.id=b.receiptId HAVING SUM(b.amount) <> a.amount`

this code returns the first row from common_fee_collection which is not proper return which i want.... i don't know my queries are right or wrong but i hope i was clear about my problem and you will try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first aggregate them and then can compare -

```
SELECT CFC.`id`, CFC.`amount`, CFCH.HEADWISE_AMOUNT
  FROM `common_fee_collection` CFC
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT `receiptId`, SUM(`amount`) HEADWISE_AMOUNT
               FROM `common_fee_collection_headwise`
              GROUP BY `receiptId`) CFCH ON CFC.`id` = CFCH.`receiptId`
 WHERE CFC.`amount` <> CFCH.HEADWISE_AMOUNT
```

Comment: thanks alot....it worked well with 50k+ rows in common_fee_collection and 800k+ rows common_fee_collection_headwise ...thanks thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```sql
SELECT cfc.*
FROM common_fee_collection AS cfc
WHERE cfc.amount != (
    SELECT SUM(cfch.amount)
    FROM common_fee_collection_headwise AS cfch
    WHERE cfch.receiptId = cfc.id
    GROUP BY cfch.receiptId
);
```

You can see the result in this [DBfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sE1t77PJgru2A93AjZiLPL/0).

Note: I see a difference between the datatypes of the fields in foreign key between the two tables: `common_fee_collection.id bigint` and `common_fee_collection_headwise.receiptId varchar(255)`

Comment: hey the query qorked well. But i'm using Mysql and i have 50k+ rows in common_fee_collection and 800k+ rows common_fee_collection_headwise so the query goes and goes for a long time and it doesn't give any output..all i have a loading screen. can you help me here?